# Convert timeframe string into an integer Java

Tags: java, string, time, integer

Lets say for example I have the String `1y2m1w5d1h`, how can I convert that into an Integer in seconds?

Where:

```
1y is 1 year
1m is 1 month
1w is 1 week
1d is 1 day
1h is 1 hour
```

But of course all of these values are optional, and changeable. So you could have `1m2h` for 1 month and 2 hours.

For simplicity purposes, lets just say 1 month is 30 days.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried?

Comment: It looks like a math problem to me, nothing special

Comment: Why would you say that 1 month is 30 days, when half the time it isn't? How long would you say that a year is? Is it 365 days, or 360? It would seem odd for 12 months not to be the same as a year... Basically, I don't think it's a useful simplification to make. You need to define a reference point in time for the calculation to be meaningful.

Comment: I said 30 to simplify things.

`30*12 = 360 and 31*12 = 372`

360 is closer to 365 than 372 is, therefore 30 is the best number to chose without knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it with a regex like this:

```
(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)
```

Then access group  2 to to determine the type. Use group one as the multiplier. And sum everything together.

Please note that it actually doesn't make sense to parse such a String, **because months and years have different lengths**, depending on the particular moment of the year.

[Here is a rough demo](http://ideone.com/AjY63K) that does not take variance of months and years into account:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Map<String, Long> times = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    times.put("y", 365L*24*60*60); // Or 366 days?
    times.put("m", 31L*24*60*60); // Or 30 days?
    times.put("w", 7L*24*60*60);
    times.put("d", 24L*60*60);
    times.put("h", 60L*60);


    String s = "1w3d4m";
    long sum = 0L;

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([A-Za-z]+)").matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
    {
        String type = m.group(2);
        String multiplier = m.group(1);
        sum += times.get(type) * Integer.parseInt(multiplier);
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
11577600
```